# How to syntax highlight for nvim treesitter when there are multiple captures?

Tags: haskell, customization, syntax-highlighting, neovim, treesitter

I am using NVIM v0.8.0-1210-gd367ed9b2 and I am trying to perform syntax highlighting for haskell in using treesitter. I would like the identifier for a function and its identifier for a function in a type definition to be highlighted differently, similar to how it is in VSCode. Currently, they are both highlighted as a function. If I perform `:TSHighlightCaptureUnderCursor` over the identifer for a function type definition, it says it is a capture of `@variable`, `@function`, `@type`. How do I highlight it as a type, and not a function?

Variables are also highlighted as functions when doing something like: `double x = x + x`. Here, although `x` is a variable, `:TSHighlightCaptureUnderCursor` says it is `@function.call(101)`, `@variable`. How would I highlight it as a variable and not a function call?